# how to Echo only the index of my $row

Tags: php, html, arrays, row

Hi I have a $row2 and I only need to echo the first index but there's something wrong with my syntax. $row2 has 5 values and I only need to echo the first.

```
<select class="input form-control" id="Intervention1" name="Intervention1" required>

<?php
    $diag = " SELECT walkindetails.IntID, intervention.IntName FROM walkindetails  INNER JOIN intervention on walkindetails.IntID = intervention.IntID  WHERE TID = '{$row['TID']}'";
    $diagarray = mysqli_query($conn, $diag);
    $intarray = array();
    if ($conn->error) {
        die("Query failed: " . $conn->error);
    }
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($diagarray)) {
        echo "   <option value=". $row2['IntName'] ." style='display: none;'>". $row2['IntName'] . "</option>";     
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Since you seem to know that "there's something wrong with my syntax", could you tell us what? You say: "$row2 has 5 values and I only need to echo the first.". We can see it has two 'values', so perhaps you mean it has five rows and you only want to echo the first row?

Comment: you can update your code according to below answers or just add `break;` after echo and you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

You got two possiblities now:

**Limiting the PHP output:**

```
<select class="input form-control" id="Intervention1" name="Intervention1" required>

<?php
$diag = " SELECT walkindetails.IntID, intervention.IntName FROM walkindetails  INNER JOIN intervention on walkindetails.IntID = intervention.IntID  WHERE TID = '{$row['TID']}'";
$diagarray = mysqli_query($conn, $diag);
$intarray = array();
if ($conn->error) {
    die("Query failed: " . $conn->error);
}
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($diagarray);
echo "   <option value=". $row2['IntName'] ." style='display: none;'>". $row2['IntName'] . "</option>";    
?>
```

This just fetches the array one time and outputs it

**Limiting the query (recommended, your database needs to support `LIMIT`):**

```
<?php
$diag = " SELECT walkindetails.IntID, intervention.IntName FROM walkindetails  INNER JOIN intervention on walkindetails.IntID = intervention.IntID  WHERE TID = '{$row['TID']}' LIMIT 1";
$diagarray = mysqli_query($conn, $diag);
$intarray = array();
if ($conn->error) {
    die("Query failed: " . $conn->error);
}
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($diagarray)) {
    ?>
    <?php echo "   <option value=". $row2['IntName'] ." style='display: none;'>". $row2['IntName'] . "</option>";     ?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Now the query only outputs one dataset

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$myVar = 1; // temporary variable for inner if statement
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($diagarray)) {
    if($myVar) {
        echo "<option value=". $row2['IntName'] ." style='display: none;'>". $row2['IntName'] . "</option>";
    }    
    $myVar = 0; // if will never evaluate to true again
 }
?>
```

Not as pretty as limiting the output, but will echo only when the if statement evaluates to true. It will only the first time around.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49004029/edit) your answer to explain why this piece of code answers the question.